# Compressed air discharge through tubing : speed of compressible flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Situation is the following :
A tank, volume $V_0$, is filled with compressed air at pressure $P_0$. Tank is big enough so that pressure $P_0$ can be considered constant, and fluid speed inside the tank $u_0=0$. A valve is suddenly open, to discharge the gaz through a straight tube of diameter $D$. At the end of the tube is the atmosphere, so $P = 1$ bar. Basically, think pneumatic potato canon, without projectile.

I'm looking to evaluate mass flow and air speed in the tubing.

To begin with, $P_0=50$ bar (but as we're ramping up testing, it could end at $P_0=200$ bar). Properties of compressed air are for $P_0=50$ bar and $T=293$K :

- $\gamma = \displaystyle\frac{C_p}{C_v}=1.4$
- $\rho_0 = 59.5$ kg/m$^3$
- Speed of sound  in this medium is $c_0=\sqrt{\gamma\displaystyle\frac{P_0}{\rho_0}}= 343$ m/s
- $D=4$ mm at the moment, may change later.

My first intuition is that I can't neglect air compressibilty at this point, so I looked back at some old lectures for compressible gas equations (named Saint-Venant equations for me, but probably not the same name in English, maybe isentropic flow Mach number relationships), and found :

$$\frac{P}{P_0}=(1+\frac{\gamma-1}{2}Ma^2)^(-\gamma/(\gamma-1))$$
Where $Ma$ is the Mach number. This leads to :
$$Ma=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\gamma-1}\left(\left(\frac{P}{P_0}\right)^{\displaystyle\frac{1-\gamma}{\gamma}}-1\right)}$$
Numerical application gives $Ma=3.2$, or 1100 m/s. I'm quite skeptical about this results, for three reasons :

1. I also saw there is a limit to flow speed given by $u_{max}=\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{2\gamma}{\gamma-1}\frac{P_0}{\rho_0}}=767$ m/s or $Ma=2.23$, lower than the previously calculated speed. And this is the limit for a discharge to vaccum, not to $P_{atmos}$.
2. I remember about the choked flow condition, limiting the flow speed at the speed of sound in a constriction, and because of the pressure ratio $P/P_0=0.02$, we are obviously lower the critical pressure ratio $\left(\frac{2}{\gamma+1}\right)^{\displaystyle\left(\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}\right)}=0.528$
3. I also remember about de Laval nozzle, and its geometry specifically designed to accelerate a compressible fluid to supersonic speed : flow speed is Mach 1 at the narrowest point (choked flow), then we have a increasing section to accelerate the fluid over Mach 1.

**So, questions:**

1. Which speed is right ? Mach 3.2 as given by Saint-Venant, Mach 2.23 as given by the maximum speed (doubt this), or Mach 1 because of choked flow ? Or another speed ?
2. As I'm quite sure it's not Mach 3.2, what's the meaning of this speed ? Or said diferently, where is my error, and in what cases is this formula usable ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: at a first look, it's hard to neglect compressibility of air at 20 MPa, standard temperature. I'll come back here in few days.